# Manticore - FACET by JSON, using the key of the JSON array

Tags: sphinx, sphinxql, manticore-search

I have an index of data in Manticore that includes a JSON field (called `readings` that is structured like this:

```
{
    "temperature": 12.3,
    "light": 45.5,
    "battery": 3422,
    ....
}
```

I'm wanting to facet the results such that I can display counts of rows matching temperature, light etc. For example:

*Readings*

- Temperature (1,305)
- Light (845)
- Battery (243)

It's important that I'm able to get the "keys" of the array to facet by (as I don't want to hard code the list of keys in my query, it should ideally be dynamic).

I can't work out how to query so Manticore FACETs on the key of the array. I was hoping for something like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM readings_data FACET readings.KEYNAME;
```

...where KEYNAME is something magical to represent the key of the array element. Is that possible?

I can restructure my JSON array if required, to make it easier to work with.

Thanks for any help or suggestions you can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only possible if you duplicate the keys in a JSON array:

```
mysql> create table fistameeny (f text, j json);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> insert into fistameeny(j) values('{"temperature": 12.3, "light": 45.5, "battery": 3422, "keys": ["temperature", "light", "battery"]}');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into fistameeny(j) values('{"temperature": 13.3, "battery": 3433, "keys": ["temperature", "battery"]}');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from fistameeny limit 0 facet j.keys;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

+-------------+----------+
| j.keys      | count(*) |
+-------------+----------+
| light       |        1 |
| battery     |        2 |
| temperature |        2 |
+-------------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Ah of course, that makes sense, thank you.